# How do you draw pictures in (La)TeX in general?

Tags: diagrams, big-list

> This can be called as a follow-up question of [Most significant reasons that led us to (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2110/156344)

There are many ways to draw graphics pictures in TeX, LaTeX and Friends. We can draw it using external programs, or use some graphics tools (Ti*k*Z, PSTricks, Asymptote, `picture` environment), etc.

So, **which graphics tool(s) / external program(s)** do you use? **Why** did you choose it(them) but not any others?

A story showing how you came to the tool is very welcome!

Comment: @Moderators Please make this a community-wiki

Comment: The original TeX engine had no graphics capability whatsoever, so even the picture environment was an improvement.  I skipped over pstricks and went straight to TikZ when I became aware of it.  I do occasionally use GIMP (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312238/how-to-create-a-tikz-picture-with-a-non-infinite-distance-viewpoint/312959?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.8355#312959).

Comment: You just can't beat a true artist https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211865/1090

Comment: I am not sure that this question really fits the site, a general question of graphics tools is too broad and off topic, and a list of TeX-implemented drawing tools comes down to the well known suspects and is probably a duplicate,

Answer (score 2):

For complicate drawings, I use https://www.mathcha.io/editor. This online editor has a WYSIWYG interface for drawing, either with the predefined shapes or freehand. When the drawing is finished, it can be exported as tikz code.

An example:

[image]