# is it posible to convert groff texts into latex using, for example, pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

Ever since I knew that one could simply spell out equations to `groff` in plain english through the use of the `eqn` macro, I wanted to take my time and learn it. Every now and then I type some really serious math in `LaTeX` (by what I mean that I spend so much time in this business. On the one side it has brought me so many benefits, like: text editors (s?ed|n?vim?); `regex`; (`vimscript`|`lua`); `tree-sitter`, `lsp` and `snippets`; it also got me into the world of mechanical keyboards and `qmk`/`via`. And this is just to name a few things). On the other side, the fact that I've been on a quest to find the perfect workflow suggests by itself that this task is very time consuming. One thing that I've learnt with my journey is to never give up sharpening that saw (for one, the time that I spend nowadays is considerably lower when compared to what I used to spend 4 years ago, when I started digging this rabbit hole).

I like the fact that I can define macros with `eqn`, which is analogous to defining my own commands in `LaTeX`. I can also create tables, figures and table of contents, number equations, make references and citations. Only two things remain open so that can I make up my mind and move definitely into `eqn`. Those are:

1. How do I get complex symbols like, for example, `\nabla`, to display correctly using `groff` and `eqn`?
2. In the very likely event that I need to convert my sources into `LaTeX`, are there any standard tools? Maybe `pandoc` can do this, but how?

P.S. At first, I planned on posting this question on `stackoverflow` but, when the website saw my tags, it redirected me to this very forum. I'm sorry if this is not the right place for making this kind of question.

Comment: Almost certainly both of your questions would be better answered by experts in groff. i would suggest trying the [groff mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/groff/) where they presumably hang out.

Comment: In general,  export anything never is a good workflow. Always there are high taxes to pay. 
Pandoc can read  man pages (roff man), so `pandoc -f man  -t latex foo.groff` maybe help (...or not, is just a not tested idea,sorry).  You can also use groff to output html and eqn to output MathML, and then I guess that `padoc -f html -t latex foo.html` could be more useful (but probably, not too much).

Answer (score 1):

Below the answer to the first question about Nabla. I don't know the answer to the second question.

The Nabla is an upside down Greek capital letter Delta. Therefore you can use https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2000-08/msg00068.html (from the Groff mailing list mentioned in comments) to reverse the Delta character, i.e., `\[*D]`.

Note that instead of setting `\v` (the vertical position) in Groff/eqn I used Postscript `x y translate` directly, as this does not increase the bounding box - in the original solution from the mailing list the height of the character consists of the full rotation around the baseline, i.e., two lines, which causes the fraction to be too high. For other sizes (like superscripts) you may need to adjust the translate values though.

Example equation taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527873 :

```
.ds Nabla "\h'\w'X'u'\X'ps: exec gsave currentpoint \
0 -6.5 translate 2 copy translate -180.0000 rotate neg exch neg exch \
translate'\[*D]\X'ps: exec grestore'\h'-\w'X'u'
.char \(Nb \*[Nabla]

.EQ
s = sqrt { { sum from i=1 to N ( x sub i - x bar ) sup 2 } over { \(Nb - 1 } }
.EN
```

Result, compiled with `groff -e example.tr > example.pdf`:

[image]